# DataGridView Edit Cell

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ado.net, datagridview

my last question was closed because it wasn't clear, so I'll try again because I really need help for this...

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with an OLEDB connection. Right now I'm developing a windows form. I noticed that a **datagridview** allows you to have an edit/add/delete mode, so I want to be able to use it.

What I want to do is have the cellcontentchanged event used to edit my database. When I change the content and leave, it'll ask me if I want to edit this cell. If I say yes, then that cell will be changed.

I made sure `ReadOnly = false` and `enabled = true`. Before, what from what I read, I would just do something like this:

```
adapter.Update(dataset);
```

or something like this. however, this does not save the changes of my databse. I'm also not sure how to edit programmatically. I'm also not sure if I should have an OLEDB update command or not. If anything is not clear, please reply and I would be glad to clarify. Thank you!

edit: sorry if its still hard to understand!

here is some code...

```
    private void dgv_DataLookup_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

        DialogResult dr;
        dr = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to edit this field?", "Edit Cell", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

        if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            //update the table in my database
        }
    }
```

this is not a lot yet, but hopefully you can try to see what i'm trying to do

edit again: This is all the relevant code for this part (this is the code that displays the datagridview that I want to edit )

```
    OleDbConnection cs;
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter();

    DataSet dsB = new DataSet();



    //If clicked search button
        else if (combo_View.Text == "Orders")
        {

            da.SelectCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM TestQuery WHERE (VendorName = @VendorName OR @VendorName = '') AND (CustomerName = @CustomerName OR @CustomerName = '')  AND ((@From IS NULL AND @To IS NULL) OR orderDate BETWEEN @From AND @To) AND (ItemNum = @ItemNum OR @ItemNum = '') AND (PO = @PO OR @PO = '') ORDER BY CustomerName", cs);

            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@VendorName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = combo_VendorView.Text.ToString();
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@CustomerName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = combo_CustomerView.Text.ToString();

            if (!chk_viewAllDates.Checked)
            {
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@From", OleDbType.Date).Value = "#" + tp_viewFrom.Value.Date.ToString("M/d/yyyy") + "#";
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@To", OleDbType.Date).Value = "#" + tp_viewTo.Value.Date.ToString("M/d/yyyy") + "#";
            }

            else
            {
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@From", OleDbType.Date).Value = DBNull.Value;
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@To", OleDbType.Date).Value = DBNull.Value;
            }

            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@PO", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txt_POLookup.Text.ToString();
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@ItemNum", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = combo_ItemNumLookup.Text.ToString();

            dsB.Clear();
            da.Fill(dsB);
            dgv_DataLookup.DataSource = dsB.Tables[0];

        }
```

please let me know if you need more code. any help is appreciated :)

Comment: @wilson - this question is still very hard to understand. 1) What environment are you working in? You mention the datagridview but this is a winforms control and you also mention asp.net. 2) What do you need to achieve? You seem to be asking to save data every time a cell changes, why not at some other time? 3) Provide some code that you have tried to give us more of an idea of what you need.

Comment: And have you looked at what you code is doing step by step? When you call adapter.Update(dataset) does your dataset actually have the changes? What happens if you cut out the datagridview and directly update the dataset?

Comment: i'm working in winforms, and any way I can update the databse would work, I just need to be able to do it from a datagridview.

Comment: @Wilson so you have a datagridview where your dataset is the datasource? And you use that dataset in the dataadapter.Update() call? Have you placed a breakpoint within the CellValueChanged event and looked at the dataset in the debugger? I think that changed should be committed here, but you should check. And have you looked at examples like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx ?

Comment: @Wilson what you are trying to do should work. It isn't too complicated so something basic must be going wrong, but these sorts of basic errors are often hard to diagnose without all the code to look at. So my advice is start with something very simple that works and take it from there. If you can't even get the dataadapter working directly then adding the datagridview only confuses things. So get a basic example working then add in more changes towards the "finished product" until something breaks, and tell us what you have done.

Comment: hi David thanks for all the help... I'm setting break points but I'm not sure where to find the values of my dgv (kinda new to all of this) I just have a question tho, do i need to use any kind of ADO.net with the Update function? or is it built in behind it already>

Comment: @Wilson To be honest, I haven't used the dataadapters in years, all my code now uses custom objects that get persisted using an ORM. When I have a second and a sql server environment I'll try your code and see if it works for me (or someone else reading will answer before that!)

Comment: @David Thanks, I'm going to try to use a binding source approach now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this myself. Just use owningcolumn owningrow to get values i needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you are asking here either, but I'll make some assumptions that you are just asking how to save the edited data back to the database.  I would not use CellValueChanged event.  Usually you just let the user edit the data in the grid and then have them click a save button or save the data on form closing.

```
void Save()
{ 
    OleDbConnection con=new OleDbConnection("Put your connect string here");
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TestQuery", con);
    OleDbCommandBuilder cb = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
    DataTable tbl = dsB.Tables[0];
    da.Update(tbl);
    tbl.AcceptChanges();
}
```

You'll probably want to reuse some of the objects you have already created like the connection but this is the basics.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried this in my code and I got this error when I used the function        Dynamic SQL generation is not supported against multiple base tables.

Comment: The select statement in the DataAdapter must be a simple select without the Where clause and only selecting from one table. In other words you can't use your original select statement or your original DataAdapter if that's what you were trying to do.  If you were using the "SELECT * FROM TestQuery" exactly and you got the error then the CommandBuilder is just too dumb and you have to create your Insert and Update command objects by hand.  That's very tedious.